# Merge items from separate lists into nested lists

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I am trying to merge two lists sequentially into sub lists. I wonder if this is possible without list comprehensions or a lambda operation as I'm still learning how to work with those approaches. Thank you

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6,7]

#desired output
c = [0,4],[1,5],[2,6],[3,7]
```

Comment: Uhh, do you mean `c=[[0,4],[1,5],[2,6],[3,7]]`?

Comment: `[list(t) for t in zip(a,b)]` This is easily turned into a more verbose loop if desired.

Comment: This is great! Thank you to all for the answers. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

An approach that doesn't involve `lambda`s or list comprehensions (not sure what the issue is with list-comps) would be with `map`:

```
c = list(map(list, zip(a, b)))
```

This first `zip`s the lists together, then creates a `list` instance for every tuple generated from `zip` with `map` and wraps it all up in `list` in order for `map` to yield all it's contents:

```
print(c)
[[0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7]]
```

This, at least in my view, is less understandable than the equivalent comprehension John supplied in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a solution suitable for beginners!

```
c = []
a = [0,1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6,7]

for i in range(min(len(a), len(b))):
    c.append([a[i], b[i]]) # writing [a[i], b[i]] creates a new list 

print(c)
```